# How can i call django view from jQuery Datatables?

Tags: jquery, django, datatables

I'm using datatables and I'm trying to add some buttons with actions to them. I want to call django view function, but I'm not sure how to achieve this inside of jQuery Datatables. When I have django templates it's clear I can just say

```
<a href="{% url 'feedback:useredit' user.id %}" class="btn text-secondary px"-0>
                                            <i class="far fa-edit fa-lg"></i>
```

and this redirect me to "useredit" view function in django. But this don't work without the django template and inside of jQuery's Datatables. Can you guys give me some hint how to achieve this?

```
             $(document).ready(function() {
                 var data;
                 fetch("http://192.168.2.85:8000/fetchapi/")
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(json => data = json)
                    .then(() => {console.log(data);
                        $('#datatable').DataTable( {
                        data:           data.employees,
                        deferRender:    true,
                        scrollY:        false,
                        scrollX:        false,
                        scrollCollapse: true,
                        scroller:       true,
                        "columns": [
                            { data: "id" }, 
                            { data: "first_name" }, 
                            { data: "last_name" },
                            { data: "email" }, 
             
                                { "data" : null, render: function ( data, type, row ) {
                                    return '<button class="btn-view" type="button">Edit</button>';
                                } },
                                { "data" : null,render: function ( data, type, row ) {
                                    return '<i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
                                } },

                        ],
                        "order": [[1, 'asc']]

                    } )
                    
                })
                } );
```

this is the whole jQuery code, but I think I need to implement the url to my django view in this part:

```
                            { "data" : null, render: function ( data, type, row ) {
                                return '<button class="btn-view" type="button">Edit</button>';
                            } },
                            { "data" : null,render: function ( data, type, row ) {
                                return '<i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
                            } },
```

I hope my question is understandable and clear, thanks a bunch for the time!

Comment: Share also your views.py.

Comment: I don't have a logic in views.py, I just create some function named employee_edit and define it in urls.py, but till now I only create django templates with edit option which redirect users to another django template for edit with the form from this template. I don't know how to achieve this without a form and template, only in datatables.

Comment: Where is your view ? You must create a view return json response first, put it in url, and declare it in you js file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion a quick solution.
You can define your url as variable:

```
var url = "{% url 'feedback:useredit' -999 %}";
```

and you can replace -**999** with your disered **id**:

```
var desired_url = url.replace("-999", "1");
// or
var href_title = "<a href='" + "{% url 'feedback:useredit' -999 %}".replace("-999", data.id) +"'>" + data.text + "</a>";
```

It is of course best to generate that in your backend method (view).

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def datatable_json(request):
    ... Your code here ...
    data["useredit_url"] = reverse("feedback:useredit", args=[user.id])
    return JsonResponse(data)
```